# How to access a Serializer field from the model's View?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to access a custom defined variable in the model's Serializer class from the model's View. But, I haven't found the correct way to do that. So, any help would be appreciated.

I've tried to take its value only by its name, but that wasn't successful.

I have this model:

```py
class candidates(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    skill = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    note = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'candidates'
```

This is the serializer for the model:

```py
class CandidatesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    experiences = CandidateExperienceSerializer(many=True)
    full_duration = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_full_duration')

    def get_full_duration(self, candidate):
        sum = 0
        for exp in candidate.experiences.all():
            if exp.work_from is None:
                exp.work_from = now()

            if exp.work_to is None:
                exp.work_to = now()

            sum += int((exp.work_to - exp.work_from).days / 30)
        return sum

    class Meta:
        model = candidates
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'gender', 'skill', 'note', 'full_duration', 
                  'experiences']
```

In the serializer, I have an additional custom field 'full_duration' where I store the full experience duration of the candidate (in months).

Finally, here's the part of the view for the model, where I have the problem:

```py
if min != 'null':
    candidates_list = candidates_list.filter(full_duration__gte=min)
if max != 'null':
    candidates_list = candidates_list.filter(full_duration__lte=max)
```

I expect the output to be a list of candidates which will have the full_duration in the range [min, max], but instead I get the following error:

**django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'full_duration' into field. Choices are: experiences, gender, id, name, note, skill**

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. `full_duration` is not a field on the model, you can't use it in filtering.

Comment: I'm asking if there's a way to filter on a serializer field, in my case that would be filtering based on the full_duration value that is calculated and shown for each candidate

Comment: @DanielRoseman is telling you: no there isn't. You cannot filter the database query based on a field calculated in python because the database has no idea of `full_duration`.

Comment: ok, thank you. Do you have any idea how could I solve this? Any thought is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: So you can do two things: either write the filter yourself in python by looping through your results (which is easy `[c for c in candidates_list if c['full_duration'] >= min and c['full_duration'] <= max]`) or do the entire calculation of `full_duration` in the database query itself by annotating your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with @dirkgroten's help, I've come up with the following solution:

```py
cans = []

for c in candidates_list:
    sum = 0
    for exp in c.experiences.all():
        sum += int((exp.work_to - exp.work_from).days / 30)

        if min != 'null' and max != 'null' and min <= sum <= max:
            cans.append(c)
        elif min == 'null' and max != 'null' and sum <= max:
            cans.append(c)
        elif min != 'null' and max == 'null' and sum >= min:
            cans.append(c)

ids = [c.id for c in cans]
candidates_list = candidates_list.filter(id__in=ids)
```